# How to count number of checkboxes selected, change background after selected, and have hover continue to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a list of checkboxes that users can select, however, limit the number of checkboxes to 5, as well as show the user how many they have currently clicked.

I also want to change the background color of the checkbox labels after they have been selected.

My main problem is that the number showing how many checkboxes have been selected is always one click behind. Also, the background color is changing after being selected, but the hover call stops working if selected.

Finally, I'd love to hear any suggestions on how to make my count function cleaner. I don't like having 7 if statements...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='group_option[]']").change(function() {
    var maxAllowed = 5;
    var cnt = $("input[name='group_option[]']:checked").length;
    if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
      $(this).prop("checked", "");
    }
  });
});

function count() {

  var count = 0;
  if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) {
    count = count + 1;
  }
  if ($('#checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
    count = count + 1;
  }
  if ($('#checkbox3').is(':checked')) {
    count = count + 1;
  }
  if ($('#checkbox4').is(':checked')) {
    count = count + 1;
  }
  if ($('#checkbox5').is(':checked')) {
    count = count + 1;
  }
  if ($('#checkbox6').is(':checked')) {
    count = count + 1;
  }
  if ($('#checkbox7').is(':checked')) {
    count = count + 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count + "/5 Selected";
}
```

```css
.options {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.options:hover {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: .15s;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
input {
  float: left;
}
label:hover {
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b id="count" style="float: left;">0/5 Selected</b>

<br>
<br>

<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option1" />
<label for="checkbox1" class="options" onclick="count(this)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 1</label>
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option2" />
<label for="checkbox2" class="options" onclick="count(this)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 2</label>
<input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option3" />
<label for="checkbox3" class="options" onclick="count(this)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 3</label>
<input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option4" />
<label for="checkbox4" class="options" onclick="count(this)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 4</label>
<input id="checkbox5" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option5" />
<label for="checkbox5" class="options" onclick="count(this)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 5</label>
<input id="checkbox6" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option6" />
<label for="checkbox6" class="options" onclick="count(this)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 6</label>
<input id="checkbox7" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option7" />
<label for="checkbox7" class="options" onclick="count(this)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 7</label>
```

Comment: Why are you binding obstrusive javascript events to the labels?

Comment: I'm quite new to javascript so I'm not sure what you mean. I would love to know a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for your separate `count()` function as you can do all the required processing in your jQuery `change` event handler (and `on*` event attributes are considered outdated and should avoided anyway). You already have the `cnt` variable stored there which you can use. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxAllowed = 5;
  
  $("input[name='group_option[]']").change(function() {
    var cnt = $("input[name='group_option[]']:checked").length;
    if (cnt > maxAllowed)
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
    else        
      $('#count').text(cnt + '/5 Selected');
  });
});
```

```css
.options {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.options:hover {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: .15s;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
input {
  float: left;
}
input:checked + label {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
input:checked + label:hover {
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b id="count" style="float: left;">0/5 Selected</b><br><br>

<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option1" />
<label for="checkbox1" class="options">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 1</label>

<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option2" />
<label for="checkbox2" class="options">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 2</label>

<input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option3" />
<label for="checkbox3" class="options">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 3</label>

<input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option4" />
<label for="checkbox4" class="options">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 4</label>

<input id="checkbox5" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option5" />
<label for="checkbox5" class="options">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 5</label>

<input id="checkbox6" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option6" />
<label for="checkbox6" class="options">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 6</label>

<input id="checkbox7" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option7" />
<label for="checkbox7" class="options">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 7</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked and looks much better! Do you know how I could also solve my css issue?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. The CSS issue is to do with the specificity of your rules on the `label` element. To override it needs to be at least a specific and appear later in the stylesheet. Check my updated CSS for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

because of the CSS tag and for the anecdote, here is a CSS possibility :

```js
// no need of javascript here, it is a CSS demo
```

```css
form {
  display: table;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.25em 1em 0 0;
  background: lightgray;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
label[for^="checkbox"]:after {/* select the labels to use to draw a checkbox*/
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 9px;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  margin:  2px  5px 0 0;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px white, inset 0 0 1px 1px gray;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, gray, white 75%)
}
/* update checkbox colors on hover/checked */
#checkbox1:checked ~ label[for="checkbox1"]:after,
#checkbox2:checked ~ label[for="checkbox2"]:after,
#checkbox3:checked ~ label[for="checkbox3"]:after,
#checkbox4:checked ~ label[for="checkbox4"]:after,
#checkbox5:checked ~ label[for="checkbox5"]:after,
#checkbox6:checked ~ label[for="checkbox6"]:after,
#checkbox7:checked ~ label[for="checkbox7"]:after,
label:hover:after {
  border: solid 1px #5586A3;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px white, inset 0 0 0 2px #9FD7F9;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #7AB6DB, white 75%)
}
/* about time to hide imputs cloned in CSS */
[name^="group_option"] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}
/* trigger the checkmark when checked */
#checkbox1:checked ~ label[for="checkbox1"]:after,
#checkbox2:checked ~ label[for="checkbox2"]:after,
#checkbox3:checked ~ label[for="checkbox3"]:after,
#checkbox4:checked ~ label[for="checkbox4"]:after,
#checkbox5:checked ~ label[for="checkbox5"]:after,
#checkbox6:checked ~ label[for="checkbox6"]:after,
#checkbox7:checked ~ label[for="checkbox7"]:after {
  content: '\2714';
  color: #223C82;
}
/* disallow option when 5 is reached */
[name^="group_option"]:checked ~[name^="group_option"]:checked ~[name^="group_option"]:checked ~[name^="group_option"]:checked ~[name^="group_option"]:checked ~ label {
  pointer-events:none;
  color:gray;
}
/* but allow to unchecked if you change yor mind */
label:hover,
#checkbox1:checked ~ label[for="checkbox1"],
#checkbox2:checked ~ label[for="checkbox2"],
#checkbox3:checked ~ label[for="checkbox3"],
#checkbox4:checked ~ label[for="checkbox4"],
#checkbox5:checked ~ label[for="checkbox5"],
#checkbox6:checked ~ label[for="checkbox6"],
#checkbox7:checked ~ label[for="checkbox7"] {
  pointer-events:auto;
  color:initial;
  background: gray;
  cursor:pointer;
}

/* add infos */
b {
  display: block;
  text-align: center
}

form {
  counter-reset: checked;
}

input:checked {
  counter-increment: checked;
}

b:before {
  content: counter(checked);
}

b:after {
  content: '5'
}
```

```html
<form>
<!-- input linked to labels to be hidden -->
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option1" />
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option2" />
<input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option3" />
<input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option4" />
<input id="checkbox5" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option5" />
<input id="checkbox6" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option6" />
<input id="checkbox7" type="checkbox" name="group_option[]" value="option7" />
<!-- end hidden input linked to labels -->
<b>/</b>
<!-- label using pseudo to draw the checkbox -->
<label for="checkbox1" class="options">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 1</label>
<label for="checkbox2" class="options">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 2</label>
<label for="checkbox3" class="options" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 3</label>
<label for="checkbox4" class="options">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 4</label>
<label for="checkbox5" class="options">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 5</label>
<label for="checkbox6" class="options">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 6</label>
<label for="checkbox7" class="options">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Option 7</label>
<!-- end label using pseudo to draw the checkbox -->
  <form>
```

[image: CSS render screenshot]
[demo to play with](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qNxXoJ)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is at line 4 of your own code...

```
function count() {
    var cnt = $("input[name='group_option[]']:checked").length;
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = cnt + "/5 Selected";
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. But the outputted number is still always one step behind.

Comment: Where are you calling the count() function? you must call it from change event, not click event.

Comment: Your right, I'm not sure what I was thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question first: the reason your losing the `:hover` state on the labels is due to [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity); you have the rule for a `label` following a `:checked` `input` *after* the rule for a hovered `label`, so the latter is being overridden. But the selector for the `:checked` rule has a higher specficity than the one for the `:hover` rule so simply changing the order of those two rules won't be enough, you'll also need to increase the specificity of the `:hover` rule.

The rest of your problems can be solved by addressing the last part of your question; simplifying your JavaScript. One way to do so would be to loop through all the inputs and listen for the `change` event on each, incrementing or decrementing the value of the `count` variable, depending on the checbox's status and the checking the value of `count` is not greater than 5.

I've added the ability to have some checkboxes initially checked and also taken the liberty of simplfying how you update the counter element and adding some CSS to make unchecked checkboxes & their labels appear disabled once 5 options have been selected in order to make it clearer that no more options can be selected.

```js
var inputs=document.querySelectorAll("input.options"),
    length=inputs.length,
    counter=document.querySelector("#count>span"),
    dataset=counter.parentNode.dataset,
    count=0,input,max=5;
while(length--){
    input=inputs[length];
    count+=input.checked;
    input.addEventListener("change",function(event){
     count+=this.checked&&1||-1;
        if(count>max){
            this.checked=0;
            count--;
        }
        dataset.count=counter.innerHTML=count;
    },0);
}
dataset.count=counter.innerHTML=count;
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:sans-serif;}
#count{
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0 0 20px;
}
input.options{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}
label.options{
    background:#e6e6e6;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    margin:0 0 1px 20px;
    padding:2px 2px 2px 20px;
    transition:background .15s;
    width:300px;
}
input.options:checked+label.options{
    background:#ccc;
}
input.options+label.options:hover{
    background:#bfbfbf;
}
#count[data-count="5"]~input.options:not(:checked),#count[data-count="5"]~input.options:not(:checked)+label.options{
    opacity:.5;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<p id="count"><span>0</span>/5 Selected</p>
<input class="options" id="checkbox1" name="group_option[]" type="checkbox" value="option1" />
<label class="options" for="checkbox1">Option 1</label>
<input class="options" id="checkbox2" name="group_option[]" type="checkbox" value="option2" />
<label class="options" for="checkbox2">Option 2</label>
<input class="options" id="checkbox3" name="group_option[]" type="checkbox" value="option3" />
<label class="options" for="checkbox3">Option 3</label>
<input checked class="options" id="checkbox4" name="group_option[]" type="checkbox" value="option4" />
<label class="options" for="checkbox4">Option 4</label>
<input class="options" id="checkbox5" name="group_option[]" type="checkbox" value="option5" />
<label class="options" for="checkbox5">Option 5</label>
<input class="options" id="checkbox6" name="group_option[]" type="checkbox" value="option6" />
<label class="options" for="checkbox6">Option 6</label>
<input class="options" id="checkbox7" name="group_option[]" type="checkbox" value="option7" />
<label class="options" for="checkbox7">Option 7</label>
```